# DocuSign API: sending a signature request via e-mail with the Envelope ID

Tags: php, docusignapi

I am trying to do the following with the DocuSign API, but I am not getting very much wiser from their documentation.

1. The admin creates the envelope in DocuSign just as they normally would, but without sending it
2. They take the Envelope ID and enter it in our software
3. We show a button to the end user that sends out the Envelope signature request when clicked (based on the Envelope ID)

The closest I came to finding something like this was https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-email-remote/ but that doesn't seem to allow me to use and existing envelope.
The API reference doesn't seem to offer any help either (https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/)

What I have got so far is the following:

1. OAuth + generating the JWT + access token (works fine)
2. generating Recipient View (which is not what I need but needs to be replaced with the right call

   ```
   $view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest(['return_url' => $args['ds_return_url']]);
   if ($args['starting_view'] == "envelope" && $args['envelope_id']) {
       $view_request->setEnvelopeId($args['envelope_id']);
   }

   # Call the API method
   $config = new \DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
   $config->setHost($args['base_uri']);
   $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $args['ds_access_token']);
   $api_client = new \DocuSign\eSign\Client\ApiClient($config);
   $envelope_api = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($api_client);
   $results = $envelope_api->createRecipientView($args['account_id'], $view_request);
   $view_url = $results['url'];

   return $view_url;
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your description it looks like for the first step, you're looking to create an [envelope as a draft](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/). Which is basically creating an envelope, filling all the information out, and then not sending it.

This will spit out an envelope Id which you can store in your application.

And when the button you describe is clicked, you can update the status of the envelope to "sent" using [this endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/update/) which will send out the envelope.

If you're looking for something more detailed, you can always reach out to us at [DocuSign Developer Support](https://developers.docusign.com/support/) and we can discuss it further.

Comment: The update endpoint was the solution indeed, thank you!